# JMeter: How can i group sample requests as one test case so that the report looks neat

Tags: ant, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I am using JMeter and Blazemeter to do some load testing. After i record a testcase say Login, I have 5 API calls recorded as part of the same testcase.
On the generating the report, My report is looks untidy and has all API calls displayed.

I tried using simple controller that did not help.

Is there a way i can display under Jmeter HTML report Login as the testcase and on expanding this section i can see the API calls?

This is how my report looks now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

[Current report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxNpg.png)[current report statistics section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lOr7.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) is what you're looking for. It can operate in 2 modes:

- `Default`: you will have 5 individual child samplers **plus** Transaction Controller containing sum of all nested samplers response times
- `Generate parent sample` - you will have only "cumulative" time instead of individual 5 samplers

See [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) article for more details.